# execute Xcode project on command line

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

I have a remote Mac server that I don't have remote desktop access. I have built my Xcode project on my local Mac and uploaded it to the remote Mac server. The problem is, how do I run the project on the remote Mac server using command line? I've uploaded all the source code and the built proj.xcodeproj to the remote Mac server. I've tried ./proj.xcodeproj but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'run' and Xcode project file. You can open it with Xcode. If you want to execute your code (which I assume you are trying to do) you have to build it first and then run the executable via Terminal.

Comment: well, you can 'run' an xcode project on the command line using the command [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html), but I'm guessing you're right that what he really wants is to run the build products.